# Best way to read text from file line by line when the text may contain '^M' with Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, readline

I am reading a tab delimited text file, where each row is ended with a new line. I have a problem of newlines inside quoted sections (this text is inserted by humans and may contain new lines within a row).

For example:

"Great feeling!  Totally recommend it!

Super comfort and it lasts!"

Which is basically the following text:

```
Great feeling!  Totally recommend it!^M\nSuper comfort and it lasts!
```

I would like to read this entire sentence as one object but to still be able to split lines in the text file by newline.

When I use the standard reading capabilities the `for line in file_object` breaks the "Great feeling!  Totally recommend it!" to one object and the "Super comfort and it lasts!" to a different one while they belong to the same sentence.

```
def readFromFile(self, filepath, delim = '\t'):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
            for line in file_object:
                yield line.strip().rstrip(os.linesep).split(delim)
```

I expect the result to be "Great feeling! Totally recommend it! Super comfort and it lasts!"

**UPDATED:**
This is my function using the CSV reader as advised below.

```
def readFromFile(self, filepath, delim = '\t'):
    with open(filepath, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
        # Use the csv reader to split by delimiter and remove EOF.
        # will handle newlines inside quoted sections of TSV files
        reader = csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=delim)
        # skip the headers
        next(reader, None)

        for line in reader:
            # Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.
            print(ascii(line))
            #yield line
    return
```

The result is:

['4', 'BNeU2UqihIwhRq9G3APK7b6ht2IZoJ21YUt4PlET', 'Super comfortable!   ', 'Really recommend it for anyone who looks for comfort and quality! ']

['5', 'BNeU2UqihIwhRq9G3APK7b6ht2IZoJ21YUt4PlET', 'Great feeling!', 'Totally recommend it!']

['\nSuper comfort and it lasts! ']

['5', 'B02uug6tF2uEA0Denhj0c9PV73y5PEOuKFmTCGb1', 'What a great button', 'bla bla bla ']

Which is easy to see that the `for line in reader` is still breaking the sentence with the `^M`.

Comment: Please post a link to the actual input file that produces this output. If the line is split like this with tab as a delimiter there must be tabs in there somehow.  This will help reproduce your behavior.

Comment: [The input file] (https://docs.google.com/a/yotpo.com/document/d/1owDzmvfRR-wQ9dr3EoOa8a10tVypjfQ6AeqmnRXCg8I/pub)

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in `csv.reader` will handle newlines inside quoted sections of CSV/TSV files: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

In your case the code might look something like this:

```
import csv

def readFromFile(filepath, delim = '\t'):
    with open(filepath) as file_object:
        for line in csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=delim):
            print('here I am:', line)

readFromFile('myfile.txt')
```

It prints:

```
here I am: ['Great feeling! Totally recommend it!\nSuper comfort and it lasts!']
```

Comment: the `for line in csv.reader()` still breaks the sentence. If I print line I get "Great feeling! Totally recommend it!" and "\\nSuper comfort and it lasts! " in a different object.

Comment: @Serendipity: Not on my system!  I have updated my answer to include the full working code for your sample input (a text file containing two lines, with a double-quote at the very beginning and end of the file).  I also included the output for the actual code under Python 2.7 for that sample input.  See if it doesn't work the same on your system with the exact code I've provided.

Comment: I'm using Python3.5. Also, note that I have ^M linebreak and not just 'normal' linebreak

Comment: @Serendipity your code already works the intended way using linux and python 3, maybe this is an OS specific issue?

Comment: @M.T I don't think my OS (mac) is the issue but rather the end-user's OS who wrote a text containing  "^M\n"

Comment: @Serendipity: I tested again using Python 3.4 and a file with "DOS style" line endings, meaning `\r\n` as shown in the output of `od -c myfile.txt`.  It still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` is the answer, but to correctly use it with Python 3, the file should be opened with `newline=''` as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).  Note especially the footnote in the link:

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

```
import csv
with open('test.txt','r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for line in r:
        print(ascii(line))
```

Output (note `^M` (ctrl-M) is equivalent to `\r` escape code):

```
['Great feeling! Totally recommend it!\r\nSuper comfort and it lasts!']
```

To split the line:

```
print(line[0].split('\r\n')) # if \r\n is consistent.
```

Or:

```
import re
print(re.split(r'\r?\n',line[0])) # if \n or \r\n is possible.
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I'm using and the unwanted output for this example.